# Does finite k-th central moment imply finite k-th raw moment?

Tags: probability, expectation

Does the existence of a finite $k$-th central moment $\mathbb{E}(|(X- \mathbb{E}X)^k|) < \infty$ imply the existence of a finite $k$-th raw moment $\mathbb{E}(|X^k|) < \infty$? 
If so how can I prove it?

I know only that the opposite is true because we can easily write any $k$-th central moment as a linear combination of raw moments with orders $k, k-1, ...,1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The idea is the same as the one you're comfortable with; use the relation
$$|X|^k = |(X - \mu) + \mu |^k$$
and expand the right side with the binomial theorem to express the $k$-th raw moment as a linear combination of the lower-order central moments.

Answer (score 2):

By the triangle inequality for $L^p$ spaces ($p\geq 1$)
$$
\lVert X \rVert_k\leq \lVert X-EX \rVert_k+\lVert EX \rVert_k<\infty
$$
for $k\geq 1$. Here
$$
\lVert X \rVert_k=(E|X|^k)^{1/k}.
$$