# Does $\mathbb{E}(X-a)^2$ finite imply $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ finite?

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Can we say that, if for some arbitrary constant  $a$, $$\mathbb{E}(X-a)^2< \infty$$ $$\implies \mathbb{E}(X^2)< \infty$$

I think that we can say, yes, because $\mathbb{E}(X-a)^2= \mathbb{E}(X^2-2aX+a^2)=a^2-2a\mathbb{E}X+\mathbb{E}X^2$

Hence, if we can show that $\mathbb{E}X$ is finite, then we would be done. I think that if $\mathbb{E}X$ was not finite, then $\mathbb{E}(X-a)^2$  would not be finite, however I am not sure how to show that this would be true.

Comment: $E(X-a)^2 < \infty$ means that $X-a\in L^2(P)$. As $a\in L^2(P)$, this implies $X\in L^2(P)$ and therefore $E(X^2) < \infty$.

Comment: Possible duplicate (or rather, a particular instance) of [Does finite k-th central moment imply finite k-th raw moment?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2511375/does-finite-k-th-central-moment-imply-finite-k-th-raw-moment)

Comment: Hint: Prove and use the inequality $$X^2\leqslant2(X-a)^2+2a^2$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The triangle inequality for $L^2$ spaces implies that
$$
\lVert X\rVert_2\leq \lVert X-a\rVert_2+\lVert a\rVert_2<\infty
$$
where $\lVert X\rVert_2=(EX^2)^{1/2}$.